# Kafka in supervisor mode

Tags: apache-storm, supervisord, apache-kafka

I'm trying to run kafka in supervision mode so that it can start automatically in case of a shutdown. But all the examples of running kafka use shell scripts and the `supervisord` is not able to note which PID to monitor. Can anyone suggesthow to accomplish auto restart of kafka?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a Unix or Linux machine, then this is when  **/etc/inittab**  comes in handy. Or you might want to use [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html). I don't know about Windows though.

Answer (score 0):

We are running Kafka under Supervisord (http://supervisord.org/), it works like a charm. Run command looks like this (as specified in `supervisord.conf` file:

```
command=/usr/local/bin/pidproxy /var/run/kafka.pid /usr/lib/kafka/bin/kafka-server.sh -f -p /var/run/kafka.pid
```

Flag `-f` tells Kafka to start in foreground. If flag `-p` is set, Kafka process PID is written into specified file.

The command `pidproxy` is a part of Supervisord distribution. Upon receiving `KILL` signal, it reads PID from specified file, and forwards the signal to the corresponding process.

Comment: I'm getting this when I try to run kafka in foreground mode USAGE: java [options] KafkaServer server.properties

Comment: This would seem to need updating for Kafka v 2.9.1_0.8.2.1 There is no kafka-server.sh, there are kafka-server-start.sh and ...-stop.sh.The only arguments the former takes is -daemon and a server.properties file. There doesn't seem to be any pid related property.