# kafka 0.8.1.1 under supervision (supervisord) does not get killed when stoping the supervisord daemon

Tags: supervisord, apache-kafka

Following the answer to [Kafka in supervisor mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21184951/101715) I had tried to do the same. Thing is, it would seem that my kafka (version 0.8.1.1) packages different run scripts. So I had tried to adapt and produced the following supervisord configuration:

```
[program:kafka]
command=pidproxy /var/run/kafka.pid /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /opt/kafka/config/server.properties 
user=kafka
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
startretries=999
log_stdout=true
log_stderr=true
logfile=/var/log/kafka/supervisord-kafka.out
logfile_maxbytes=20MB
logfile_backups=10
```

I use the following rpm of supervisor:

```
[root@dev-xxx yyy]# rpm -qi supervisor
Name        : supervisor                   Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 3.0                               Vendor: obs://build.opensuse.org/home:presbrey
Release     : 13.1                          Build Date: Thu 13 Jun 2013 08:35:40 AM IDT
```

**stoping the supervisord daemon does not kill off kafka** see below:

```
[root@dev-xxx yyy]# jps
3236 core
31378 QuorumPeerMain
31408 Jps
2964 Kafka
31293 supervisor
31246 nimbus

[root@dev-xxx yyy]# supervisorctl status
kafka                            RUNNING    pid 2963, uptime 1 day, 5:15:18
storm-nimbus                     RUNNING    pid 31246, uptime 0:02:06
storm-supervisor                 RUNNING    pid 31293, uptime 0:01:44
storm-ui                         RUNNING    pid 3236, uptime 5 days, 22:37:33
storm-zookeeper                  RUNNING    pid 31378, uptime 0:00:47


[root@dev-xxx yyy]# service supervisord stop
Stopping supervisord: Shut down
Waiting roughly 60 seconds for /var/run/supervisord.pid to be removed after child processes exit
Supervisord exited as expected in under 12 seconds


[root@dev-xxx yyy]# supervisorctl status
unix:///var/tmp/supervisor.sock no such file


[root@dev-xxx yyy]# jps
2964 Kafka
31474 Jps
```

Comment: Can you try to add `stopasgroup=true` to supervisor's kafka section and see if this works?

Comment: Perfect thanks! Would you like to add it as an answer so I could upvote and mark?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, as I said earlier `stopasgroup=true` should help. I'm not 100% sure about the exact reasons, but from my understanding, it's because kafka is started by the shell script and, by default, on tear down, only that script will be killed.

Comment: Where can I add the option you mentioned?

Comment: @SonOfSun to supervisord section related to kafka, exact position does not matter